# table width with colspan in html

Tags: html

I need a clarification regarding colspan and width in html. Why can't I set width to a column that is spanned?

```html
<table width='520'>
<tr>
<td width='60'><strong>A</strong></td>
<td colspan='2' width='100'><strong>B</strong></td>
<td colspan='2' width='100'><strong>C</strong></td>
<td colspan='2' width='100'><strong>D</strong></td>
<td width='60'><strong>E</strong></td>
<td align='center' width='100' ><strong>F</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='60'></td>
<td width='50'></td>
<td width='50'></td>
<td width='50'></td>
<td width='50'></td>
<td width='50'></td>
<td width='50'></td>
<td width='60'></td>
<td width='100'></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The code is in above format. The column shrinks when there is no data, and column size increases when data size becomes larger.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply change size of colspanned column because it has to fit to other columns in this table. It it a **table** constraint.

Beneath you have two columns with **width=50** for every one double-column with **colspan** it means that it has to has **width=100** which is actually **2 * 50**.

You can modify you colspanned column with by modifying single columns width or adding more columns.

Comment: Thank you buddy. But why the column shrinks when there is no data, even after the width is specified.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "shrink" - please look at this example to understand it better: https://jsfiddle.net/kt96ty94/ - try to midify width of exmpty column between **A** and **C** and see that nothing is happened until you'll modify width of columns beneath